# What are use cases to use `SecureRandom.base64` over `SecureRandom.hex`?

Tags: ruby

**Objective** is to create a random encoded string. But I'm not a computer science major, any explanation in layman terms would be much appreciated.

```
irb(main):002:0> SecureRandom.base64
=> "9VpzpvCR4ww/ZQc9lN148A=="
irb(main):003:0> SecureRandom.hex
=> "29b6cd61ec3e58959b006b6d98550b97"
```

Comment: See the source code at https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-base64 and https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-hex ?

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help. I already looked at the source code and did not understand, hence the question.

Comment: These are not Ruby concepts, you should learn what [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and [Hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) are. The question as asked doesn't really make it clear what you're asking. Do you want to know what the difference is between these two functions, or which is better suited to generating random passwords?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @meagar. Feedback like that is much more conducive to refining my question. Just plainly listing documentation and down voting without feedback is poor etiquette.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between Base64 and hex is really just how bytes are represented. Hex is another way of saying "Base16". Hex will take two characters for each byte - Base64 takes 4 characters for every 3 bytes, so it's more efficient than hex. ... If it does matter, then clearly Base64 is better on that front.

Comment: Thanks for the simple breakdown!